# Dropping the first element of a 3 element tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

Is there a way to drop the first element of a 3 element tuple, so I get a 2 element tuple without having to make another function for this purpose?

> (a,b,c)->(b,c)

Basically I have to use a function, which creates a 3 element tuple and then I have to use a function that only uses the last two element of it.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question *almost* has the required function itself!

```
\(a,b,c)->(b,c)
```

is the function you need. It is an "anonymous" function defined on the fly, you need not give it a name. So for example if you have

```
someFunc :: someType -> (Int, Char, Bool)
```

You could do

```
(\(a,b,c)->(b,c)) (someFunc someValue)
```

to get the second and third component of `someFunc someValue`.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I thought of, but it *is* creating a function. I think using something else that provides patter matching (`let` or `where`) is better for a problem like this.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis : True. But since the function is defined "inline" and does not introduce another name, I thought it wasn't too bad. :-)

Comment: Ha, that was actually exactly my logic too. But then I remembered how pointlessly picky some teachers and graders can be.

Comment: Sadly there seem to be no functions like `curry`, `uncurry`, `fst`, and `snd` in the standard library for 3-tuples. Otherwise we could have done it pointlessly!

Answer (score 5):

You can do pattern matching with several syntactic constructs like `let`. So you could do something like:

```
let (a, b, c) = triTuple in fn (b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case`:

```
case x of (a, b, c) -> (b, c)
```